# How to write an if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: shell

```
for filename in *
do
    if [ "$filename" -ne even ] && [ "$filename" -ne odd ]
    then
        echo "$filename"
    fi
done
```

Above is a simple shell script that checks the files in the current repository and outputs the file whose names are not "even" and "odd"

Wont work

Comment: one way to go is `[ $filename -ne even -a $filename -ne odd ]` but I know there are others and I'll let someone better versed on the topic enlighten you in full. `-a` by the way is the `test` way of saying "and".

Comment: No, `-a` is the `test` way of saying "and".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams corrected! That's why I'm letting someone better versed than me to give a precise answer.

Comment: If you are using `sh` then @man0v's solution is correct.  If you are using `bash` than the better way is `[[ $filename != even && $filename != odd ]]`

Comment: Difference between double bracket and single bracket?

Comment: Double bracket is for the bash extended test and single bracket is for POSIX stuff.  Also note that with both shell and bash the `-ne` comparison operator is for integers and shouldn't work with strings like `even` or `odd`

Comment: `-ne` is for numeric (integer) comparisons.  `!=` is for string comparisons.  With `-ne`, you should be getting an error message like `bash: [: even: integer expression expected`.   If your shell is bash, try running `help test` to see the various tests and operators supported by `[ ... ]` aka `test`.

Comment: Thx @cas that cleared up a lot and jesse_b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `if` line to:

```
if [ "$filename" != even ] && [ "$filename" != odd ]
```

In the `bash` shell, the entire script, (*i.e.* from `for` to `done` inclusive), can be simplified to:

```
GLOBIGNORE=even:odd ; printf "%s\n" *
```

Another `bash` method:

```
shopt -s extglob  # only needs to be done once, if not set already.
printf "%s\n" !(odd|even)
```

Answer (score 16):

The comparison operator `-ne` is an *arithmetic* test operator, i.e. it compares only integers:

```
i=7

if [ "$i" -ne 6 ] && [ "$i" -ne 8 ]; then
   echo 'i is neither 6 nor 8'
fi
```

To compare *strings* for inequality, use `!=`:

```
if [ "$filename" != 'even' ] && [ "$filename" != 'odd' ]; then
    printf '"%s" is neither of the strings "even" or "odd"\n' "$filename"
fi
```

Or, using `case`:

```
case "$filename" in
    even|odd)
        # the filename is "even" or "odd"
        ;;
           *)
        # the filename is neither "even" nor "odd"
        printf '%s\n' "$filename"
esac
```

---

Also note that `*` will match any name in the current directory, not just names of regular files.  To be sure that you only process regular files in your loop, use

```
for name in *; do
    if [ ! -f "$name" ] || [ -L "$name" ]; then continue; fi

    # other code here using "$name"
done
```

The `continue` statement skips to the next iteration of the loop. `-f file` checks for *regular* files *after* symlink resolutions, so if we want files of type *symlink* to also be excluded regardless of whether they point to a regular file or not, we also need that extra `|| [ -L "$name" ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Or one bracket pair with -a

```
for filename in *
do
     if [ "$filename" != even -a "$filename" != "odd" ]
     then
         echo "$filename"
     fi
done
```

or

```
for filename in * 
do 
    case "$filename" in  
        (even|odd) ;; 
            *) echo "$filename" ;; 
    esac
done
```

Comment: Note that POSIX has deprecated the use of `-a` and nowadays recommends using two separate tests with `&&` in between.

Comment: You're right, but the solution with two tests and && is already in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -not -name even -not -name odd
```

might be the shortest solution, despite the verbose "-maxdepth 1", but in directory leafs, you may omit it.

Calling a program for each file is pretty straightforward:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -not -name even -not -name odd -exec wc {} ";"
```

(as shown with wc, which expects a filename, where the curlies are used. Relying on GNU-find here.)